# I am interested in learning how to optimize my Action Property of an object in my SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am interested in learning how to optimize my Action Property of an object in my SSRS Report.

All of the linked reports use the same Data Source.  So, should I put the Data Source in the Shared folder and have all the report projects in the same solution?

The Action properties for the object have the options under "Enable as an action":

Go to report
Go to bookmark
Go to URL

The option for "Go to URL" works for the main report that is sent as an email alert subscription, but, as for the other reports that launch in a browser, I wonder if the option "go to report" will be a better choice?  Would it be, and how would that be set?

Well, this answers part of my question:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Go to report action is mostly used to go to a subreport, where you hand over a parameter or a value. If you dont pass any of these Go to URL would be the better choice.

How you handle your datasets depends on your setup. If your reports load fast and the datasets also, dont bother with shared datasets. Just load the same dataset again.

You can also insert a sever between your database and the report server which caches all the datasets. So you just load your dataset once in the morning and the reports use the cached one.